# Fill Drop down On select Of Drop down

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

how to fill dropdown values on selection of multiple dropdown.for example i have following Dropdown list.
[image]
On select of second dropdown i wants to fill Third Dropdown With Single selection How can i do. ?
My current code for this is as follow.

```
  //CALL FOR SECOND DROPDOWN 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select4').on('change',function(){
        var subcatgoryId = $(this).val();
        console.log(subcatgoryId);
        if(subcatgoryId){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax_load_specification.php',
                data:{subcatgoryId: subcatgoryId},
                success:function(html){
                  alert(html);
                  //$('#select5').html(html);
                  //$('#loading1').css("display","none")
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                  alert("Got Some Errore");
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#select5').html('<option value="">Select Category first</option>');
        }
    });
  });
```

and php code is as follow

```
if(isset($_POST["subcatgoryId"]) )
{
    $subcategory = explode(',', $_POST["subcatgoryId"]);

    print_r($_POST["subcatgoryId"]);
    foreach ($subcategory as $key => $value) 
    { 
        echo $key;
        echo "<br>";
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM m_subcategory WHERE id = ".$item." ";
        $query1 = $conn->query($query1);
        $query1 = $query1->fetch_object();

        if($query1){
            $id = $query1->id;
            $name = $query1->name;
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';  
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">We Get Empty Category</option>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly the same kind of way you did with the first one. Get the currently selected value, make an ajax request, populate the next dropdown. There's not really any difference. Except if dropdown 1 changes later, you might need to reset both dropdown2 and dropdown3, because the value in dropdown2 isn't there any more to make the options in dropdown3 appear. That's really the only thing you might need to change in your approach. It's hard to see why this is giving you a problem. What are you worried about?

Comment: P.S. You don't need two separate `document.ready` blocks. One is enough.

Comment: can you suggest code ?

Comment: 99% of it will be basically the same as what's in your `$('#select2').on('change',function(){`, except with the field names, URL etc changed as needed.

Comment: But When I Alert Values It will return as 396,395,316. So how can i store ? 
its better if you suggest code.

Comment: I assume this means that "select4" allows multiple selections. But it doesn't change much - you can just pass that string of values to the server in the ajax call. Then the server can split the values (using the comma to separate) and use them as values in whatever query it uses to get the results from the database. You haven't shown any server code so I can't help with that, but what you've said doesn't really require any change in the javascript code.

Comment: i got data as ["44", "43", "42", "41"] array in php page so i explode data anf foreach that data but still its not work. for more you can see My Question Update

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What response do you get back from the server? What does `html` look like, in the "success" of your ajax call? P.S. You can use `WHERE id IN (44, 43, 42, 41)` so you can run the query just once, which will be quicker. You can loop through the array in order to build in the string for the IN clause. I suspect your problem is that at the moment you use an `$item` variable in your SQL which isn't populated anywhere - your `foreach` is producing `$key` and `$value` (although you don't have an array key, so `foreach ($subcategory as $value)` would make more sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use For Loop And it starts working

```
if(isset($_POST["subcatgoryId"]) )
{
    $subcategory  = $_POST["subcatgoryId"];
    $len=count($subcategory);

    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) { 

        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM m_subcategory WHERE id = ".$subcategory[$i]." ";
        $query1 = $conn->query($query1);
        $query1 = $query1->fetch_object();

        if($query1){
            $id = $query1->id;
            $name = $query1->name;
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">We Get Empty Category</option>'; 
        }
    }

}
```